# How do you hide a modern SharePoint list column when printing the view/new/edit item form?

Tags: modern-experience, css

I have a modern SharePoint list where my client wants to see all columns on the screen but hide some in any printed output. The columns that are to be hidden contain confidential data and allowing them to be printed is considered a risk. Is there a way to hide certain columns in printed output via the use of a print style sheet (or some other method)? If so, how do you reference the columns to be hidden in the style sheet and how do you then associate the style sheet with the view/new/edit item forms? Thank you for any assistance you're able to offer.

Comment: How are you printing the list forms? using browser print option or using customized 
 solution (Power apps / SPFx)?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Thanks for your reply. I'm a big fan of your videos. The form would be printed via the browsers print option.

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case you cannot do anything from SharePoint modern experience list forms side.